# What is wrong with my aproach for detecting open serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, thread-safety, locking

This is the code snippet which preceds the part that dispatches serial data.

```
while (true)
{              
     if (serial.IsOpen)
     {
          lock (dispatch_lock)
          {                 
              serial.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
          }
     }
}
```

So first I check if serial is open and if so I lock it so that other threads can't close it. Despite that sometime i get
`Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
The port is closed.`

What is wrong in my aproach to ensure that the port is only written to when opened?

Comment: how does your code look that closes the serial port?

Comment: The lock is placed incorrectly, IsOpen can race as well.  Move it up so the IsOpen test is inside the lock braces.